# Reverse estimate on the Riesz potential $I_\alpha : L^{n/\alpha}\to \mathrm{BMO}$

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis

$\newcommand\BMO{\mathrm{BMO}}$Consider the Riesz potential on $\mathbb{R}^n$ given by
$$
I_\alpha f(x) = c_{n,\alpha} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{f(y)}{\lvert x-y\rvert^{n-\alpha}} dy.
$$
It is known that $I_\alpha : L^{n/\alpha}\to \BMO$ is bounded. My question is : given a function $f\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $I_\alpha f \in BMO(\mathbb{R}^n)$, can we deduce some integrability on $f$ ?

Comment: Wouldn't that imply that $BMO$ is isomorphic to $L^{n/\alpha}$? Note that this is impossible since $L^p$ is reflexive for all $p\in (1,+\infty)$ whereas $BMO$ is not reflexive.

Comment: Thank you for your remark, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment. I guess that your question is "If I know that $\lvert D_x\rvert^{-\alpha} f$ belongs to $\mathrm{BMO}$, what can I say about the regularity of $f$?" I guess that $\alpha$ belongs to $(0,n)$.

You start from
$$
\lVert\lvert D_x\rvert^{-\alpha} u\rVert_\mathrm{BMO} \le C\lVert u\rVert_{L^{n/\alpha}},
\tag{1}\label{1}$$
but I fail to see how you could gain something from this inequality. I think that
$$
\text{$\lvert D_x\rvert^{-\alpha}$ sends the Hardy space $\mathscr H^1$ into $L^{n/(n-\alpha)}$},
$$
which is stronger than \eqref{1}. None of these properties survive if you replace $\mathrm{BMO}$ by $L^\infty$ or
$\mathscr H^1$ by $L^1$.